# Web service does not work when deployed on IIS

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, web-services, iis

I want to use google map to display some gps coordinates. I am using a web service inside a ajax query. The problem I am facing is when I deployed the app on IIS the web service does not work, whilst it works perfectly when not deployed. Perhaps there is something special I have to do first, but it is weird.
Here are my codes :

Web service

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function Test(ByVal idinst As String) As String
    Dim entites As New epgar_formEntities
    Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim listPatient As New List(Of A5349_DOT_DAILY_REPORT_BY_PROJECT_Result)
    Dim patient As New A5349_DOT_DAILY_REPORT_BY_PROJECT_Result
    listPatient = DalManager.DailyReportByProject(idinst)

    Dim query As New List(Of A5349_DOT_DAILY_REPORT_BY_PROJECT_Result)
    query = From o In listPatient Select o.LATITUDE, o.LONGITUDE, o.AGENT
    Return jss.Serialize(query)
End Function
```

Ajax query :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "webservice.asmx/" + webmethod,
        data: JSON.stringify({idinst:'' + project}),  
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
        var rs = JSON.parse(data.d);

         for (var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
          putMarker(rs[i]['LATITUDE'], rs[i]['LONGITUDE'], "Marker Test", "images/marker_rouge.png");
         }
        },
        error: function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

However, this works.

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function Test(ByVal idinst As String) As String
    Dim entites As New epgar_formEntities
    Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim listPatient As New List(Of A5349_DOT_DAILY_REPORT_BY_PROJECT_Result)
    patient.LATITUDE = "18.32344"
        patient.LONGITUDE = "-72.79875"
        patient.AGENT = "user"

        patient1.LATITUDE = "18.32344"
        patient1.LONGITUDE = "-72.79875"
        patient1.AGENT = "user"

        patient2.LATITUDE = "18.32344"
        patient2.LONGITUDE = "-72.79875"
        patient2.AGENT = "user"

        listPatient.add(patient)
        listPatient.add(patient1)
        listPatient.add(patient2)
    query = From o In listPatient Select o.LATITUDE, o.LONGITUDE, o.AGENT
    Return jss.Serialize(query)
End Function
```

Please if you any idea, your are very welcome.

Comment: Try debugging the AJAX query in your browser, at the very least write values to your console to make sure what's being passed is what's expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MahendranNadesan. However, the probleme is not in the ajax query, it is in the web service which return this error : web service system.argumentnullexception: value cannot be null.